# Cucumber report naming and maven-cucumber-reporting trends

Tags: maven, cucumber-java

**Background info:**

- Maven version: 3.2.5
- Java version: 1.8
- Cucumber reporting version: 3.8.0
- cucumber-java, cucumber-spring, and cucumber-junit: all version 1.2.5

I have a maven java project. I have cucumber tests and the maven-cucumber-reporting plugin running and working for the project.

Here is how I am running the Cucumber tests:

```
package com.util.test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = false, features = "src/test/resources/features", format = {"pretty", "json:src/test/report/cucumber.json"}, tags={"@test, @util"})
public class UtilCucumberTest {

}
```

And here is my pom with the maven-cucumber-reporting plugin:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
     <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
     <executions>
          <execution>
               <id>testing</id>
               <phase>test</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                    <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
<cucumberOutput>${project.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                    <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                    <buildNumber>${project.version}</buildNumber>
               </configuration>
          </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Each time I run a build the cucumber.json file is overwritten and I lose previous build info. I would like to keep a copy of each report (or one per build, as in --report.json). I currently do not see the *Trends* page either and would like to see this information.

**Questions:**

1. What do I need to do to see the *Trends* information in the pretty HTML report that is generated?
2. How can I get cucumber to generate a uniquely named .json report file each time I run a build (or one unique report per version build)? And will this allow me to see the trends section comparing previous reports?

Comment: Which Cucumber version are you using?

Comment: @Marit 3.8.0, haven't touched this in a while. I see 3.13.0 is now the newest. Also, we will probably solve this issue outside of the Maven build process via automation (Jenkins).

Comment: @weslatz There is no Cucumber-jvm v3.8.0; are you referring to the reporting version?

Comment: @Marit yes, that is the reporting version. I am using cucumber-java, cucumber-spring, and cucumber-junit all version 1.2.5

Comment: Thanks. Note that the latest cucumber version is now 2.3.1 (group id has changed to io.cucumber). If you've solved it in Jenkins, let us know? ;)

Comment: @Marit haven't had the chance to setup in Jenkins, but will post if I do. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550153/maven-cucumber-reporting-with-multi-modile-maven-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638372/correct-maven-pom-configuration-for-cucumber-tests-and-maven-cucumber-reporting) I have many questions about using Cucumber with Maven, and adding Jenkins into the mix may make things simpler or only complicate them further... yet to be determined

Comment: All good question I unfortunately cannot help you with. Have you tried any of the Cucumber support options like the Slack channel?

Comment: @Marit Good suggestion :) I should try there next

Comment: See you there :)