# Correct maven pom configuration for Cucumber Tests and maven-cucumber-reporting

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

I had this working in a previous project but cannot find it now...

I am using Maven to build a java app and I am running tests on the app during the build process. I am using *maven-cucumber-reporting* plugin v3.0.0 to put together a report of the outcome.

I want to:

1. Run the cucumber tests
2. Generate a report (whether or not the cucumber tests fail)
3. Fail a build after generating reports if failed

How can I setup my pom with a combo of *maven-surefire-plugin*, *maven-cucumber-reporting* plugin, and any other plugins to make this work?

**Update 1:**

Here is my current pom configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                        <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                        <buildNumber>${project.version}</buildNumber>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-file</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber.json</sourceFile>
                        <destinationFile>${project.parent.basedir}/src/test/report/cucumber-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.json</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I get the cucumber tests to run during `maven-surefire-plugin`, not fail before the `maven-cucumber-reporting` and `copy-rename-maven-plugin` plugins run to generate my reports and put them in the right place (multi-module pom where I am aggregating tests at parent), *AND THEN* fail the build?

Currently conditions 1 and 2 pass (my Cucumber tests run, fail, and then reports are generated, but the build does NOT fail).

Maybe more generically, how can I run tests as part of a maven build, then execute some reporting plugins, then fail the build after the reporting plugins run?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used `format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"}` in the runner, as per the example at [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_reports.htm)

Comment: I am creating cucumber JSON reports, which is what I want, then using the maven-cucumber-reporting plugin to generate a more extensive HTML report. I will update the question with more from my pom to make it clearer.